# Currency contribution in Portfolio Performance

Tags: investing

when I enter my transactions in Yahoo Finance I don't see a field where I can enter at which exchange rate I bought the shares. So for a EUR Portfolio holding US and Swiss stocks how do I see the effect curreny rates have on my portfolio?

Thank you!